# The implication of zero mixed partial derivatives for multivariate function's minimization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative

Suppose $f(\textbf x)=f(x_1,x_2) $ has mixed partial derivatives $f''_{12}=f''_{21}=0$, so can I say: there exist $f_1(x_1)$ and $f_2(x_2)$ such that  $\min_{\textbf x} f(\textbf x)\equiv \min_{x_1}f_1(x_1)+ \min_{x_2}f_2(x_2)$? Or even further, as follows: 
$$f(\textbf x)\equiv f_1(x_1)+ f_2(x_2)$$

A positive simple case is $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_2^3$. I can not think of any opposite  cases, but I am not so sure about it and may need a proof.

Comment: Concerning the passage from $f(\textbf x)\equiv f_1(x_1)+ f_2(x_2)$  to $\min_{\textbf x} f(\textbf x) = \min_{x_1}f_1(x_1)+ \min_{x_2}f_2(x_2)$, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1592211).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a mixed derivative $f_{xy} = 0$, integrating with respect to $y$ gives:
$$
f_x(x,y) = \int  f_{xy} \,dy   + h(x).
$$
Integrating with respect to $x$:
$$
f(x,y) = \iint  f_{xy} \,dydx  + \int h(x)dx + g(y).
$$
Similar result yields if we start from $f_{yx}$, now this implies
$$
f(x,y) = f_1(x) + f_2(y),
$$
and there goes your conclusion in the question.

Comment: Hi again. Can I say $f_1$ and $f_2$ are unique? Excluding constants.

Comment: @jorter.ji If you only know that the mixed derivative is zero, then any differentiable function $f_1$ and $f_2$ will do. So not unique unless you have other conditions.

Comment: Like what kind of conditions? Or can you think of any instances such that $f=f_1+f_2=f_3+f_4$?

Comment: @jorter.ji I meant to say that provided only this differential relation $f_{xy} = f_{yx} = 0$ is known, then there are infinitely choices for $g$ and $h$ in $f = g(x) + h(y)$, $f$ can be $f = x+y$, or $f= x^2+y^2$. Not that they are equal or something.

Comment: OIC your meaning. Actually, I already know that $f(x,y)=f_1(x)+f_2(y)+V(x,y)$, where $V(x,y)$ is a implicit but determined function, i.e., $f(x,y)$ is somehow implicitly determined, then I wonder if $f=g(x)+h(y)$ is unique.

Comment: @jorter.ji If $f$ is implicitly determined, then $f$ is known, and the uniqueness of this representation $f = g(x)+h(y)$ depends on $f$. For example $$ x^2 + y^2 + |f(x,y)|= 1,$$ and now $f$ can be $\pm(1-x^2-y^2)$, which one would you choose?

Comment: Sorry for bring it back again. But I want to know if your answer (proof) holds for a general function $f(x_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_n)$ with $f''_{ij}=0$? I am not sure.

Comment: @jorter.ji Should be true, you can first try proving it for dimension 3, then by induction. You can ask a new question about this generalized result if you want.

Comment: Hi, Mr. Cao, how can I chat with you? I have further doubts. I think your proof needs further assumption. For example, it fails on the function $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x,x\ge y\\y,x<y\end{cases}$$

Comment: @jorter.ji The proof hiddenly assumes that all the first partial derivatives are continuously differentiable, in order to use the integration type of proof above. In the example above, this condition is not met.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Shuhao Cao needs an assumption that the first partial derivative is integrable.

Here I try to provide proof without that assumption.

#### Restatement

Let us restate the conjecture under slightly weaker conditions:

If $f(x, y)$ has $f_{yx} = 0$, then there exists functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(y)$, so that $f(x, y) = f_1(x) + f_2(y)$.

#### Proof

From [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), $$f_y(x, y) = f_y(0, y) + f_{yx}(\xi , y) x, \xi \in (0, x)$$This implies $f_y = f_y(0, y)$.

$\forall x_0$, $f(x_0, y)$ is an antiderivative of $f_y(0, y)$. [Any two antiderivatives differ by constant](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Primitives_which_Differ_by_Constant). So, we can write that $$f(x, y) = f(0, y) + c(x) = f(0, y) + f(x, 0) - f(0, 0) = f_1(x) + f_2(y)$$

#### Annotation

The key is that "any two antiderivatives differ by constant" can be proved only based on Mean Value Theorem, but nothing wih Reimann Integral.

Comment: Is there a type on the line "If $f(x,y)$ has $f_{yx}=0$, then $z(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$"? I think it should read "If $z(x,y)$ has $z_{yx}=0$, then $z(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$".  Otherwise, it seems incomprehensible: what is $z$? and is the domain of $f$ one or two dimensional?
.

Comment: @SRobertJames You're right. Thanks for your correction. I have fixed this typo.