# $f(x,y) = f_1(x) + f_2(x)$ with continuous differential real-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $f$ is a continuously-differentiable real-valued function on an open interval in $E^2$ and $\ \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x{\partial y}} = 0$, then how are there continuously differentiable real-valued functions $f_1, f_2$ on open intervals in $R$ such that $f(x,y) = f_1(x) + f_2(y)$?

This does not make much sense to me. Could someone provide some proof explaining how this could be possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure  $f_1(x)$  and  $f_2( x)$ ? Isn't  $f_1(x)$  and  $f_2( y)$  ?

Comment: Is $f$ twice differentiable?

Comment: I believe it is implied that $f$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The implication of zero mixed partial derivatives for multivariate function's minimization](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428662/the-implication-of-zero-mixed-partial-derivatives-for-multivariate-functions-mi)