# $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = 0 \nRightarrow f(x,y) = g(x) + h(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am working through Ted Shifrin's book Multivariable Mathematics. There is an exercise problem that is meant to demonstrate that one can have
$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = 0$ but$ f(x,y) \neq  g(x) + h(y)$.

The question (3.6.11) is as follows:
$$ \mathrm{Given} \; f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 0, \; x < 0\; \mathrm{or} \; y < 0 \\x^3, \; x \geq 0 \; \mathrm{and} \; y > 0 \end{cases} $$

1. Show that $f$ is $C^2$
2. Show that $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = 0$
3. Show that  $f(x,y)$ cannot be written as $g(x) + h(y)$ for appropriate functions $g, h$.

---

I see that the domain is the entire plane except the x-axis, that is $\mathbb{R}^2 -\{y=0\}$.
The function is then 0 in all quadrants except the first, where it is $x^3$.

I could show 1. and 2. above, but I am puzzled by two things.

Q1 What's wrong with writing $f(x,y) = g(x) + h(y)$ piecewise in each quadrant ?

Q2. Will anything change if the domain allows the line $y=0$ also ?

Q3. What is the takeaway from this problem ? I do not  understand that.

Comment: For Q2, note that $lim_{y\rightarrow0^{+}}f(1,y)=1$, whereas $lim_{y\rightarrow0^{-}}f(1,y)=0$, so the function cannot be continuously extended to the positive x-axis. The function is already defined equal to 0 on the negative x-axis, by the first piecewise condition.

Comment: The domain is the entire plane minus the **nonnegative** part of the $x$-axis. The negative part of the $x$-axis is included in the first condition “$x<0$ or [...]”, so $f$ is defined (equal to zero) there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Q1; defining the quadrants requires both $x$ and $y$. For example, defining
$$g(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0   &\text{ if } x<0\  \text{ or } \; y < 0, \\
x^3 &\text{ if } x\geq0 \; \text{ and } \; y > 0.
\end{array}\right.,$$
does not make sense as now $g(x)$ depends on $y$. More formally; if $f(x,y)=g(x)+h(y)$ then for all $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\Bbb{R}^2$ we have
$$f(x_1,y_1)+f(x_2,y_2)-f(x_1,y_2)-f(x_2,y_2)=0.$$
But this is clearly not the case, take for example $x_1=y_1=1$ and $x_2=y_2=-1$.

---

For Q2; the given function $f(x,y)$ does not extend to a function differentiable on $\Bbb{R}^2$. There are no functions with this property that are differentiable on all of $\Bbb{R}^2$. See also [this excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428662/the-implication-of-zero-mixed-partial-derivatives-for-multivariate-functions-mi).

---

For Q3; the takeaway is that the implication
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}=0
\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad
f(x,y)=g(x)+h(y),$$
depends crucially on the domain; it holds if the domain is $\Bbb{R}^2$, but not if the domain is, for example, a disconnected subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Could you provide an example  of a function like that defined  on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: The  bit about the  domain of g(x) needing to be described by y is just mindblowing, many thanks to you for the answer, and to Professor Shifrin for the question.  Its easy to forget that a function and its domain are inseparable.

Comment: I think Q1 has to be answered in affirmative. E.g. for the first quadrant  $f(x,y)=x^3+0$, so is $g(x)=x^3$ and $h(y)=0$

Comment: @RafaBudría I do not understand; Q1 is not a yes/no question.

Comment: Answering in affirmative to the question Q1 is, to my understanding, say that it is correct writing $f(x,y) = g(x) + h(y)$ piece wise in each quadrant.